# T-SQL: Parse XML Data in from classes which inherit from a common base,

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I'm trying to parse XML data in SQL Server. I have a XML column in a table, the XML stored in it can vary by type, but they all inherit from the same base type.

Row 1: has XML like so:

```
<Form>
  <TaskType>1</TaskType>
  --Other Properties ...
</Form>
```

Row 2: has XML like so:

```
<License>
  <TaskType>2</TaskType>
  --Other Properties ...
</License>
```

Normally I might parse XML with this T-SQL code snippet:

```
SELECT  
    xmlData.A.value('.', 'INT') AS Animal
FROM
    @XMLToParse.nodes('License/TaskType') xmlData(A)
```

This doesn't work since in a view since I'm dependent on the name to find the node.

How can I always find the `TaskType` XML element in my XML content?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Okay ill update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

XPath is using asterisk `*` as a wildcard.

http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/xpathwildcard.php

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata XML);
INSERT @tbl (xmldata) VALUES
(N'<Form>
    <TaskType>1</TaskType>
    <TaskName>Clone</TaskName>
    <!--Other XML elements-->
</Form>'),
(N'<License>
    <TaskType>2</TaskType>
    <TaskName>Copy</TaskName>
    <!--Other XML elements-->
</License>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT ID
    , c.value('(TaskType/text())[1]', 'INT') AS TaskType
    , c.value('(TaskName/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS TaskName
FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/*') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

| ID | TaskType | TaskName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Clone |
| 2 | 2 | Copy |

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can just interate the nodes like so without being aware of their name:

```
SELECT  xmlData.A.value('.', 'INT') AS Animal
FROM    @XMLToParse.nodes('node()/TaskType') xmlData(A)
```